Proving $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{n+2} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k}{k+3} = \infty$
This is a question I got on a homework assignment, and my solution. This is the first exercise about sequences, therefore formality is very important, and we haven't discussed series, so any theorem regarding series is not relevant here.
Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{n+2} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{k+3} = \infty$
Solution:
We know that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{n+2} = 1$, therefore, if we show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{k+3} = \infty $, we can deduce that their product goes to infinity.
Let us look at the sequence $a_k = \frac{k}{k+3}$. By arithmetic of limits, we get that the limit of $(a_k)$ is $1$.
Therefore, there is $K \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $k>K$: $\frac{k}{k+3} > \frac12$.
Therefore, there is $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n > N+2$:
$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{k+3} = 
\sum_{k=1}^{N+2} \frac{k}{k+3} + \sum_{k=N+3}^n \frac{k}{k+3} >
\sum_{k=1}^{N+2} \frac{k}{k+3} + (n-(N+2)) \cdot \frac12 > 
\frac{n-(N+2)}{2}$
The sequence $(\frac{n-(N+2)}{2})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \longrightarrow \infty$ .
$\Rightarrow$ the sequence $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{k+3} \longrightarrow \infty$
We can conclude that the original sequence, goes to $\infty$.
My main goal, is to show that from a given point, the sum of two consecutive elements in the sum is greater than 1, therefore, the sequence which is defined by the sum approaches infinity.
Any feedback will be kindly appreciated!

More simply, $\frac k{k+3}≥\frac 14$ for all $k\in \mathbb N$, hence the given sum is $≥\frac n4$ which clearly goes to $\infty$.

While your solution is correct, I think you are complicating things unnecessarily. You could simply bound $\frac{k}{k+3}$ by $\frac{1}{4}$ and thus have $\frac{n}{n+2} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{k+3} > \frac{n}{n+2} \times\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{4} = \frac{n}{n+2} \times\frac{n}{4} = \frac{n^2}{n+2}$ which clearly goes to infinity.

Your work is fine but you could go further.
$$S_n= \frac{n}{n+2} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k}{k+3} = \frac{n}{n+2} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k+3-3}{k+3}= \frac{n}{n+2} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left(1-\frac{3}{k+3}\right)$$
Using harmonic numbers
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k+3}= H_{n+3}-\frac{11}{6}$$
$$S_n=\frac{n}{n+2} \left(n-3 H_{n+3}+\frac{11}{2}\right)$$ Using the asymptotics
$$H_p=\log (p)+\gamma +\frac{1}{2 p}-\frac{1}{12 p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^4}\right)$$ Replacing and continuing with Taylor series
$$S_n=n-\frac{1}{2} (6 \log (n)+6 \gamma -7)+\frac{12 \log (n)+12
   \gamma -35}{2 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ which is a very good approximation.
